# Validation on dynamically generated options in choice field + Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony

I have 3 dropdowns. The first dropdown is visible. When you select a value in the first dropdown, an ajax call is made and pulls data according to the selected value and add the options to the second dropdown that gets visible. Same for the third when you select a value in the second dropdown.

But the problem is now, when I want to submit the form that I always get a validation error `This value is not valid.` on the second and third dropdown. Is there a way how I can fix this? Or maybe disable the validation on these last two fields?

In my register form type I have

```
->add('player', new PlayerType())
```

In my Player form type I have

```
->add('team', new TeamType(), array(
      'label' => 'Team*',
      'required' => false
))
```

And in my TeamType I have

```
$builder
        ->add('competition', new CompetitionType())
        ->add('teamName', 'choice', array(
            'empty_value' => 'Kies uw competitie.',
            'label' => 'Team'
        ))
    ;
```

And in CompetitionType I have:

```
$builder
        ->add('region', 'entity', [
            'label'    => 'Regio',
            'class'    => 'VolleyScoutBundle:Regions',
            'property' => 'regionName',
            'empty_value' => 'Kies uw regio.'
        ])
        ->add('competitionName', 'choice', array(
            'empty_value' => 'Kies uw competitie.',
            'label' => 'Competitie'
        ))
    ;
```

I'm getting errors at competitionName and teamName. I load the data in jquery like this:

```
$('#register_player_team_competition_region').on('change', function() {
    var region_id = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: getCompetitonsUrl,
        data: {
            regionid: region_id
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            $(data).each(function( index, val ) {
                $('#register_player_team_competition_competitionName').append("<option value='" + val.value + "'>" + val.label + "</option>");
                $('#register_player_team_competition_competitionName').trigger("chosen:updated");
                $('.competition').removeClass('hide');
                $('.competition').css('display', 'block');
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    })
});

$('#register_player_team_competition_competitionName').on('change', function() {
    var competition_id = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: getTeamsUrl,
        data: {
            competitionid : competition_id
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            $(data).each(function( index, val ) {
                $('#register_player_team_teamName').append("<option value='" + val.value + "'>" + val.label + "</option>");
                $('#register_player_team_teamName').trigger("chosen:updated");
                $('.team').removeClass('hide');
                $('.team').css('display', 'block');
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    })
});
```

My register view:

```
{% extends "::securitybase.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}Register | {{ parent() }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% set class_error = ' has-error' %}
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-sm-offset-3"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/volleyscout/images/volleybal.png') }}" width="40" height="40" alt=""> VolleyScout</h1>
        {{ form_start(registerForm, {"attr": {"class": "form-horizontal"} }) }}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personalia</legend>
            <div class="form-group{{ registerForm.userFirstname.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.userFirstname, label|default(),
                {"label_attr": {"class": "col-sm-3 control-label"} }) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{ form_widget(registerForm.userFirstname,
                    {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.userFirstname.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.userFirstname) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group{{ registerForm.userSurname.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.userSurname, label|default(),
                { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{ form_widget(registerForm.userSurname,
                    {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.userSurname.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.userSurname) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group{{ registerForm.userType.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.userType, label|default(),
                { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{ form_widget(registerForm.userType,
                    {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.userType.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.userType) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class='teams'>
            <legend>Team</legend>
            <div class="form-group{{ registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber, label|default(),
                { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{ form_widget(registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber,
                    {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group{{ registerForm.player.playerBirthyear.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.player.playerBirthyear, label|default(),
                { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{ form_widget(registerForm.player.playerBirthyear,
                    {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.player.playerBirthyear.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.player.playerBirthyear) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="position form-group{{ registerForm.player.playerPosition.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.player.playerPosition, label|default(),
                { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{ form_widget(registerForm.player.playerPosition,
                    {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.player.playerPosition.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.player.playerPosition) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="region form-group{{ registerForm.player.team.competition.region.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.player.team.competition.region, label|default(),
                { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{ form_widget(registerForm.player.team.competition.region,
                    {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.player.team.competition.region.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.player.team.competition.region) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="competition hide form-group{{ registerForm.player.team.competition.competitionName.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.player.team.competition.competitionName, label|default(),
                { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{ form_widget(registerForm.player.team.competition.competitionName,
                    {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.player.team.competition.competitionName.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.player.team.competition.competitionName) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="team hide form-group{{ registerForm.player.team.teamName.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.player.team.teamName, label|default(),
                { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{ form_widget(registerForm.player.team.teamName,
                    {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.player.team.teamName.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.player.team.teamName) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account</legend>
            <div class="form-group{{ registerForm.userEmail.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.userEmail, label|default(),
                { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"} }) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                        {{ form_widget(registerForm.userEmail,
                        {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.userEmail.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.userEmail) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group{{ registerForm.username.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {{ form_label(registerForm.username, label|default(),
                { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        {{ form_widget(registerForm.username,
                        {"attr": {"class": "form-control" } }) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if not registerForm.username.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {{ form_errors(registerForm.username) }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group{{ registerForm.password.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
                {% for passwordItem in registerForm.password %}
                    {{ form_label(passwordItem, label|default(),
                    { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"} }) }}
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            {{ form_widget(passwordItem,
                            {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {% if not registerForm.password.vars.valid %}
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                        {% for passwordItem in registerForm.password %}
                            {{ form_errors(passwordItem) }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                {{ form_widget(registerForm.btn_register,
                {"attr": {"class": "btn btn-primary"} }) }}
                <a href="{{ path('volley_scout_loginpage') }}" class="btn btn-link">Inloggen</a>
            </div>
            {{ form_end(registerForm) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: show us some code otherwise it's too hard to guess the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both choice fields , `competitionName` and `teamName` have no values , you gave them a label and an empty value and since you havent explicity mentionned that they are not required `symfony` will set them as required in the rendred form.

so either you set them as not required :

```
->add('competitionName', 'choice', array(
        'empty_value' => 'Kies uw competitie.',
        'label' => 'Competitie',
        'required' => false // they are no longer required 
    ))
```

or you gave values to the choice field :

```
->add('competitionName', 'choice', array(
         //choices here 
        'choices'   => array('footbal' => 'Footbal', 'swimming' => 'Swimming'),
        'empty_value' => 'Kies uw competitie.',
        'label' => 'Competitie',
        'required' => false
    ))
```

Comment: And when the view returned with the errors, my dropdown select value is the empty value ..

Comment: you have constraints that are failing, check fields type and if you have set constraints to them ( not blank for example )

Comment: Also when I don't check if the form is valid (in action, controller). The data is not send ..

Comment: are you getting the same message ? and did this message appears when you set values to the choice fields ( using `choices` option ) ?